# Magento - Add a active class to a product that has been added to wishlist

Tags: magento

Im my magento store i have a icon that displayed add to wish-list. How to i add a class (To the wish-list button) to the product when its added to the wish-list, to i can change the icon i am using?

Basically so when user browses the products in the search they can see what products they have added. A "active" class is added so i can apply a css rule to display another icon, one different from add to wish-list.

I have search and looked around for an answer or a push in the right direction and have struggle.

Answer (score 1):

you can use getWishlistItemCollection to get the collection of items added to wishlist.

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Wishlist/Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data.html#methodgetWishlistItemCollection

For ex :

```
$_itemCollection = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlistItemCollection();
$_itemsInWishList = array();

foreach ($_itemCollection as $_item) {
    $_product = $_item->getProduct();

    $_itemsInWishList[$_product->getId()] = $_item;
}

return $_itemsInWishList;
```

Then in product loop inside listing page template you can check whether the product id exists in above array or not and add class accordingly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`

you can determine in this way

```
$isAddedInWishilist = false;
$_wishlistCollection = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlistItemCollection();
if($_wishlistCollection){
    $_wishlistCollection->addFieldToSelect('product_id');
    $_wishlistCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$_product->getId());
    if(count($_wishlistCollection)==1)
        $isAddedInWishilist = true;
}
```